# PYTHON list searching for value repetition

Tags: python

I have a file with 8 columns and 100+ rows looks like:

```
PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997  
PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003  
PAIR 345G 3 SODIUM 23 CARBON 14 1.664  
PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506
```

What I want to do is to compare the 5th column to find out repetition of any value and then generate an outfile containing the two full lines.

Comment: Like Mat said. What have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.split()` to split up the lines

Use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` to keep track of the repetition

eg.

```
>>> lines = """PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997  
... PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003  
... PAIR 345G 3 SODIUM 23 CARBON 14 1.664  
... PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506  """.split("\n")
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> D = defaultdict(list)
>>> for line in map(str.split, lines):
...     k = line[4]
...     D[k].append(line)
... 

>>> [v for k,v in D.items() if len(v) > 1]
[[['PAIR', '1MFK', '1', 'URANIUM', '82', 'HELIUM', '112', '3.6997'], ['PAIR', '4IG5', '4', 'LITHIUM', '82', 'ARGON', '99', '2.5506']]]

>>> [(k,v) for k,v in D.items() if len(v) > 1]
[('82', [['PAIR', '1MFK', '1', 'URANIUM', '82', 'HELIUM', '112', '3.6997'], ['PAIR', '4IG5', '4', 'LITHIUM', '82', 'ARGON', '99', '2.5506']])]
```

Comment: how i would be able to write this output in an outfile in a format as it was in input...??

Comment: ....res_seg1 = 'output you generated above...'


out = open("c:/users/abhisek/desktop/new folder/1h2b.netw",'w')
#itering through the data with a 'for' loop...
for record in res_seg1:
    for case in record:
        caseAsString = str(case)
        out.write(caseAsString)
        out.write('\n')
out.close()
now this gives me an outfile like following.....['PAIR', '1h2b', '14', 'A', 'HELIUM', '157', 'ARGON', '158', '2.950']... but i want to have a format where '' & , will not be there and seperation space of each word will be equal...

Comment: @abhisek, you should use `' '.join(case)` instead of `str(case)`

Comment: You see in the question i have provided the list have equal spacing but values looks like distorted.  So, please tell me how could I be able to make the output list such a way that values for every column remain just one below another.  I have tried using '\t' but that gives me equal spacing not a perfect arrangement.

Comment: @abhisek, Perhaps you could add an example of the desired output with correct formatting to your question. Maybe the formatting you need is worth asking as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that uses `setdefault` (i.e., you don't have to import `collections`:

```
>>> lines = [
... 'PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997',
... 'PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003',
... 'PAIR 345G 3 SODIUM 23 CARBON 14 1.664',
... 'PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506',
... 'PAIR AB32 4 KRYPONITE 98 ARSENIC 99 2.3406'
... ]
>>> d = {}
>>> for line in lines:
...     d.setdefault(line.split()[4], []).append(line)
...
>>> [(k, v) for k,v in d.items() if len(v) > 1 ]
[('82', ['PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997', 'PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506']), ('98', ['PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003', 'PAIR
B32 4 KRYPONITE 98 ARSENIC 99 2.3406'])]
```